# what is the difference between createStore and createStoreWithMiddleware in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I found two ways to configure redux createStore ,

1.https://github.com/TeamWithBR/SampleProjectTodo/blob/master/src/store/configureStore.js

2.https://github.com/aknorw/piHome/blob/9f01bc4807a8dfe2a75926589508285bff8b1ea6/app/configureStore.js

Which is preferable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`createStoreWithMiddleware` is the old way to create the store with enhancers in Redux. In [Redux version 3.1.0](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/releases/tag/v3.1.0), a new approach has been introduced and now `createStore` receives an enhancer such as `applyMiddleware()` as the last optional argument.

Now, the new `createStore` approach is preferable as it leads to code that is easier to read and reason about, but both will work.