# redux-thunk: actions must be plain objects

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I have been trying to use `redux` and `redux-thunk` to help get a json file from a api and have been getting a warning stating that `action must be a plain object`. I am really confused as to where the issue is in the code. i have tried following many other stackoverflow posts and a couple of guides online and have not really got a good grasp of where I am going wrong. I understand that this is a problem with how I am referencing `async` and `dispatch` but do not know how to fix it.

This is the function that causes the warning to appear in the simulator

```
export const fetchData = url => {
  console.log("Should enter async dispatch");
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchingRequest());
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          let json = response.json();
          dispatch(fetchingSuccess(json));
          console.log("JSON", json);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch(fetchingFailure(error));
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
  };
};
```

Here is the output in the console

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

Edit: including setup of middleware

I have the middleware setup in the index.js file of my app

index.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import React, { Components } from "react";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import appReducer from "./src/data/redux/reducers/appReducer";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(appReducer);
console.log("Store", store.getState());
const AppContainer = () => (
  <Provider store = {store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppContainer);
```

I learned this implementation of store from a Youtube Tutorial.

Edit 2: Adding in the `fetchData` call

I call `fetchData` in a `_onPress` function like this

```
_onPress = () => {
    const {fetchData} = this.props;
    let url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10";
    fetchData(url);
    console.log("should have fetched");
  };
```

this is how my app has been connected to `redux`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { response: state };
};

const mapStateToDispatch = dispatch => ({
  fetchData: url => dispatch(fetchData(url)),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapStateToDispatch
)(SearchScreen);
```

these are the action in my app

```
export const fetchingRequest = () => {
  {
    type: FETCHING_REQUEST;
  }
};

export const fetchingSuccess = json => {
  {
    type: FETCHING_SUCCESS;
    payload: json;
  }
};

export const fetchingFailure = error => {
  {
    type: FETCHING_FAILURE;
    payload: error;
  }
};
```

Comment: First thing to eliminate is setup. Please include your code for how you created the store to make sure that you have the thunk middleware applied correctly.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the setup of the store.

Comment: Ok looks fine, though you may be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44214222/what-is-the-difference-between-createstore-and-createstorewithmiddleware-in-reac) as a cleaner/recommended pattern for creating your store. Next thing is how are you calling `fetchData`? Please include that code in your question as well. These requests may seem tedious but they are all part of [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - it makes the question valuable for future users.

Comment: I have included how i am called `fetchData` and how i have connected it to the `redux` incase it is needed as well.

Comment: Copy pasting your code, I get no error. However, I have subbed out `fetchingRequest`, `fetchingSuccess`, and `fetchingFailure` with plain objects as that is what I assume is returned by those functions. Obvious question next: did you install the redux-thunk library?

Comment: Yes, I have installed redux-thunk as version 2.3.0 and I will include my actions creators in an edit incase that is the problem.

Comment: I have found an answer to my problem, if you look below. Thank you very much for working the problem through, Redux has very much been the hardest part of building this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem thanks to working through the steps in the comments thanks to Michael Cheng. I ended up finding that the problem was that i had actions with plain objects but they were not returning anything.

The original actions were

```
export const fetchingRequest = () => {
  {
    type: FETCHING_REQUEST;
  }
};

export const fetchingSuccess = json => {
  {
    type: FETCHING_SUCCESS;
    payload: json;
  }
};

export const fetchingFailure = error => {
  {
    type: FETCHING_FAILURE;
    payload: error;
  }
};
```

to this

```
export const fetchingRequest = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_REQUEST
  }
};

export const fetchingSuccess = json => {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_SUCCESS,
    payload: json
  }
};

export const fetchingFailure = error => {
  return {
    type: FETCHING_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  };
};
```

with including the `return` for each action